# Why we should use log(1+Age) rather than log(Age)?

Tags: finance

Normally, when calculating the firms age in finance, I saw that people usually use

**firm age= log(1+age).**

Apart from the reason documented by [Loderer, 2009](https://www.efmaefm.org/0EFMAMEETINGS/EFMA%20ANNUAL%20MEETINGS/2009-Milan/papers/405.pdf) that we avoid the age of zero that log(0) makes no sense, is there any other reason?

Comment: It has the nice feature that when Age is small, log((1+Age)=Age

Comment: I have also seen (statistics) people use it for smoothing purposes when dealing w/ categorical variables (like age), see [this Wiki on "add-one" smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing).

Comment: I think the main reason for the "1+..." is what you said, "that log(0) makes no sense".

Comment: @KevinT lovely for the smoothing idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As some people have already answered,

1. It's more comfortable to expand it in Taylor Series, since:

\begin{equation} \ln(1+x) = - \displaystyle\sum \frac{(-x)^n}{n}, -1 < x \leq 1 \end{equation}

On the other hand, we would end up with

\begin{equation} \ln(x) = - \displaystyle\sum \frac{(-(x-1))^n}{n}, -1 < (x-1) \leq 1  \end{equation}

2. Most of the time we would like to "begin counting" at zero. In other words, we would like to have

\begin{equation} D(\textrm{Age}) = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{R}^- \end{equation}

Which is only possible when we translate the logarithmic function to the left. Otherwise, we would end up at $\ln(0)$, as you previosuly mentioned to be avoided.